# PDO:getting around echoing result of fetch and fetchAll

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, web-deployment

I have a table with four fields in it.I can change my query to show me what i want,which is,two of the four fields.I want php to do this for me.

```
    $stmt=$db->query("select * from remote");
                $result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                foreach($result as $row){
                        echo $row;
                }
```

This gives me the first 'row' of my table with all elements in it.My table is something like

```
    --------------------------
    |id|name|position|my_box|
    --------------------------
    |1 |bear|3       |5     |
```

At the moment I have 4 rows.With fetchAll I have no idea how to echo them out in a readable way(not using print_r).How can I print like, Id=>Value and only Id or Value.

Comment: Instead of `*` use the fields you want, `id`. I don't see a `value` column. I also would just loop the `fetch`.

Comment: `echo $row['name']`

Comment: The point is to not change the query..

Comment: @Riz Why not? Your doing more work than needs to be done with this query.

Comment: Sorry i didnt explain myselt  better..I can but at this time I can't.It's like an 'exercise' and I am asked to do it this way,for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch rows `while` they exist:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['id'], ' - ' ,$row['name'], '<br />';
}
```

Comment: This worked for me but how to generalize?I mean if i did'nt know about id and name in my case?

Comment: One more question..what's the difference between you doing fetch in while statement while i did earlier and passed as $result.Because I tried your code my way and my pc crashed(exhasted RAM)..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
        echo $field . ' => ' . $value . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `fetchAll` fetches __array of all__ rows, so `$value` is array.

Comment: The problem I have is to have just the 'id' and 'name' field without changing my query.

Comment: You may use `if (in_array($field, array('id', 'name'))) { echo $field . ' => ' . $value . '<br>'; }` but I would suggest that you use u_mulder solution for this case (`$row['id']` etc.).